# Labels keep rotating 90º. Is there a way to aplay the rotate oº and use the the LinePlacement at the same time?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm using the LinePlacement in order to place the label in a corner or my bounding boxes, the problem is that for some reason the labels sometimes are rotated 90º. Is there a way to force them to have the 0º rotation, and also have the LinePlacement?

This is what I'm doing now:

```
<LinePlacement>
  <PerpendicularOffset>
    10
  </PerpendicularOffset>
</LinePlacement>
```

And this is what I get:

[image: Obtained result]

Note: I've tried to use:

```
<PointPlacement>
  <Rotation>
   0.0
  </Rotation> -->
</PointPlacement>
```

But I then the label appears in the middle of the bounding boxes.

What I'm trying to get is this:

[image: expected result]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What you are trying to do seems to make no sense - can you add some screen shots or pictures to show what you are trying to do and what actually happens

Comment: I hope that with those pictures it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to get what you want out of the box, a label that somehow sits outside of the geometry it belongs to, at its bottom right.
It should be possible to get there by writing new filter functions that extract the label point you want, from the original geometry. That requires [some Java programming though](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html).